# java.beans.Introspector getBeanInfo does not pickup any superinterface's properties

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

I just noticed that java.beans.Introspector getBeanInfo does not pickup any superinterface's properties. Example:

```
public interface Person {
    String getName();
}
public interface Employee extends Person {
    int getSalary();
}
```

Introspecting on Employee only yields salary even though name is inherited from Person.

Why is this? I would rather not have to use reflection to get all the getters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is covered in Sun bug
[java.beans.Introspector doesn't work for interfaces](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4275879)

Answer (score 3):

The Java VM does not support this out of the box as [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185004/java-beans-introspector-getbeaninfo-does-not-pickup-any-superinterfaces-properti/867423#867423) wrote. I also needed this and implemented a [helper class](http://kenai.com/projects/deut/sources/repo/content/trunk/src/diergo/util/BeanHelper.java) as part of [Diergo Utils 1.5](http://kenai.com/projects/deut).

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
public static BeanInfo getBeanInfo(Class<?> beanClass, Introspector.USE_ALL_BEANINFO);
```

and see if this yields the result you're looking for.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. My solution was introspect the superclass and parent interfaces by calling the class's getInterfaces() and getSuperclass().

Comment: Do you only want the properties?  You can get the property descriptors from BeanInfo, I believe it contains all the properties including ones from superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you should write a custom BeanInfo class.

Comment: note that you'll need to define getAdditionalBeanInfo() if you have define a custom BeanInfo